# Entry into the European Union with Greek visa

Tags: algerian-citizens

I have a Greek visa but may I enter France because it's near my country and economic competitor, thus it's possible if there isn't a negative impact on my visa request the next time.

(Original French:) salut ....J'ai un visa de grec Mais puis-je entrer en France  car c'est proche de mon pays et de mon adversaire économique....Donc c'est possible
S'il n'y a pas d'impact négatif sur la demande de visa la prochaine fois

Comment: Grec doit-être la pays primaire de ton voyage, eh?

Comment: Sorry, this is an English site, pull your text through Google translate if necessary. And please mention Algeria in your question as well, that is clearer.